# ActivityProvider does not run

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

While the application is calling a web service, I want to show an activity indicator.

So I created the service, the method which is calling the service and the view.

I tested everything with the an android emulator without any troubles, but if I want to debug it on a phone (LG G6), the activity indicator is not spinning..
The control is visible, but the animation is not working...

This is the code:

```xml
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Clicked="Button_OnClicked"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="Press"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
     <StackLayout
         x:Name="StackLayout"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Padding="30"
         BackgroundColor="Black"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         IsVisible="False"
         Opacity="0.8"
         VerticalOptions="Center">
           <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="White" />
           <Label
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               Text="Loading..."
               TextColor="White" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

CodeBehind

```cs
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StackLayout.IsVisible = !StackLayout.IsVisible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The external grid row has enough height to show both the `ActivityIndicator` and the `Label`?

Comment: @MateusW. yes..I added a screenshot from the ActivityIndicator

Comment: Quite strange that it is showing but not running. Are you settings `IsRunning` to false anywhere in your code? Try checking the property with a breakpoint to see if it is correctly set. Also, other conflicts in your page may be causing the `ActivityIndicator` to not work.

Comment: I use the same property for IsVisible and IsRunning... so I think that the property is correctly set and notify the user interface.. because the control is also visible..

Comment: @D.Nehl, According to your code, I test at my side, it works fine, so can your provide one demo that can reproduce your issue here?

Comment: @CherryBu, I added a demo code, which has the same behavior..  
I think the problem is the phone or the Android OS (8.0.0) on the phone.. I have to test it with a different phone..

Comment: @D.Nehl, I have test your code at my decive android version 5.0, 6.0, It works fine, so I guess that the problem is your phone.

Comment: @CherryBu, Thanks! I just tried different apps like youtube, with the same problem..  I also tried it with the simulator and the same android version and the indicator worked.
So its definitely the phone..